# Difference between initializing a string and not initializing a string in .NET

Tags: .net, string, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

I would like to know how is memory allocated when initializing a string using the new keyword and when setting a value to the string without the new keyword.

Abishek R Srikaanth

Comment: I would like to understand how this behaves in .NET

Comment: @shakeofabiomen Initialization is not the same as memory allocation. Initialization means you set a value to a given variable for the first time.

Comment: Please note that `String` doesn't have a constructor that creates an instance from a literal.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the way you initialize it with new keyword or when you directly set the string using '='. The memory is both allocated on the heap and so garbage collector is reponsible for collecting the memory once it goes out of scope. The only differentce is 'new' calls the constructor whereas if you directly assign using = the overloaded operator gets called and it initializes a new instance of the string.

Comment: This is for C# which i am specifying.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. does the same happen for other types as well? (Like Int)